Littlewood-Paley characterization of nonhomogeneous Sobolev space.
Recently I have been self-studying Littlewood-Paley theory using Bahouri-Chemin-Danchin's textbook, "Fourier Analysis and Nonlinear Partial Differential Equations" as the main source. During the process, I came across an example stated by the authors which I cannot give an explicit proof for.
To begin with, let me introduce the notations in use. The Dyadic partition of unity used by the authors is a couple of smooth functions $(\varphi,\chi)$ such that $\varphi$ is supported in the annulus $\{\xi\in\mathbb{R}^d: \alpha^{-1}\leq |\xi| \leq 2\alpha\}$, $\chi$ is supported in the ball $\{ \xi\in\mathbb{R}^d: |\xi|\leq \alpha\}$ and
$\forall \xi\in\mathbb{R}^d, \chi(\xi) + \sum_{j\geq0} \varphi(2^{-j}\xi)=1$. Denote by $h$ and $\tilde{h}$ the inverse Fourier transform of $\varphi$ and $\chi$, respectively.
Then the nonhomogeneous Littlewood Paley decomposition of a tempered distribution $u\in\mathcal{S}'$ is defined as
$\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}} \Delta_j u$
where
$\Delta_j u=0$ when $j\leq-2$, $\Delta_{-1}u = \tilde{h}\ast u$, and $\Delta_j u = 2^{jd} h(2^j \cdot)\ast u$ for $j\geq 2$.
Now my concern lies in the first example in page 99, where the authors wrote "By (2.10) and
and the Fourier–Plancherel formula, we find that the Besov space $B^s_{ 2,2}$ coincides with the Sobolev space $H^s$ defined on page 38." That is, the following characterization of nonhomogeneous Sobolev space via Littlewood-Paley decomposition holds:
A tempered distribution $u$ belongs to $H^s$ if and only if the sequence $(2^{js}||\Delta_j u||_{L^2})_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}$ belongs to $\ell^2(\mathbb{Z})$.
This is where I got stuck. I have tried using the authors' hint by utilizing the Fourier-Plancherel formula and inequalities (2.10) but I still cannot work out the proof of the above characterization of nonhomogeneous Sobolev space. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!
Added material:

Let $s\in\mathbb{R}$. The nonhomogeneous Sobolev space is defined as

$H^s=\{u\in\mathcal{S}': \hat{u}\in L^2_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d) \text{ and } \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} (1+|\xi|^2)^s|\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 d\xi < + \infty\}$.

The Inequalities (2.10) are

$1/2 \leq \chi^2(\xi) + \sum_{j\geq0} \varphi^2(2^{-j}\xi)\leq 1$.

After some discussion with my lecturers and my friends, I think I have figured out the answer to my question. The key idea is to use Fourier-Plancherel formula to derive
$||\Delta_j u||_{L^2}^2=||\mathcal{F}(\Delta_j u)||_{L^2}^2, \forall j\in\mathbb{Z}$.
Next, the algebraic identity $\mathcal{F}(u\ast \phi)=\mathcal{F}(u)\mathcal{F}(\phi)$ for all $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ gives us
$||\Delta_{-1} u||_{L^2}^2=||\Delta_{-1} u||_{L^2}^2=||\chi u||_{L^2}^2 = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\chi^2(x)|\hat{u}(x)|^2 dx $.
For $j\geq0$, the rescale property $2^{jd}\mathcal{F}^{-1}(\varphi)(2^j \cdot)= \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\varphi(2^{-j}\cdot))$ yields
$||\Delta_j u||_{L^2}^2=||\varphi(2^{-j}\cdot) u||_{L^2}^2$.
Hence,
$\displaystyle{\sum_{j\in\mathbb{Z}}2^{2js}||\Delta_j u||_{L^2}^2= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\hat{u}(x)|^2(2^{-2s}\chi^2(x)+\sum_{j\geq0}2^{2js}\varphi^2(2^{-j}x))dx}$.
Now to make the Sobolev norm pop out, we use the following "trick":
$\displaystyle{\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|\hat{u}(x)|^2(2^{-2s}\chi^2(x)+\sum_{j\geq0}2^{2js}\varphi^2(2^{-j}x))dx= \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}(1+|x|^2)^s|\hat{u}(x)|^2 \frac{(2^{-2s}\chi^2(x)+\sum_{j\geq0}2^{2js}\varphi^2(2^{-j}x))}{(1+|x|^2)^s}dx}$.
Then the inequalities in (2.10) can be applied to derive the final estimates.
Edit: English is not my native language so there could be some confusing sentences in my arguments. I would love to receive feedback from everybody to broaden my knowledge. Thank you very much!
